# SwiftUI - How to translate NSImage for macOS to UIImage for iOS

Tags: swift, swiftui, drag-and-drop

I am following this tutorial to learn about drag and drop with SwiftUI.
https://swiftui-lab.com/drag-drop-with-swiftui/

This is my first time working with getting an image from a URL and the code in the tutorial uses NSImages for macOS, however, I need to build for iOS, therefore, NSImage must be changed to UIImage.

I was able to translate the NSImage to UIImage in the DragableImage struct, however, I am having trouble with the GridCell struct image. Specifically with unwrapping the URL into the img variable and returning it as an overlay on top of the Rectangle. See below code.

```
struct GridCell: View {
            let active: Bool
            let url: URL?
            
            var body: some View {
            // translate NSImage to UIImage here
                let img = Image(nsImage: url != nil ? NSImage(byReferencing: url!) : NSImage()) 
                    .resizable()
                    .frame(width: 150, height: 150)
                
                return Rectangle()
                    .fill(self.active ? Color.green : Color.clear)
                    .frame(width: 150, height: 150)
                    .overlay(img)
            }
        }
```

Any help to translate NSImage to UIImage is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using iOS 15 - use `AsyncImage` instead to load from URL.

```
let img = AsyncImage(url: url)
```

Documentation here: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/asyncimage

---

If you need to support iOS 14 or lower, one way to create a `UIImage` from `URL` is by defining an extension:

```
extension UIImage {
  static func fromUrl(url: URL?) -> UIImage {
    if let url = url,
      let data = try? Data(contentsOf: url),
      let image = UIImage(data: data) {
      return image
    } else {
      return UIImage()
    }
  }
}
```

Then use it as:

```
let img = Image(uiImage: UIImage.fromUrl(url: url))
```

Note: if using `UIImage` and loading remote images, you probably want to load the image asynchronously, not on main thread and maybe in `.onAppear` - but that is beyond the scope of this question.

Comment: Thank you! Worked great. Accepted as the answer.